# Better way to CURL to WCF

Tags: c#, php, json, wcf, curl

I am able to post to a web-service I wrote in C# from PHP via a CURL request, but I cannot get the request to go through correctly. No matter what I do, the only way that I can get the post to show up is if I `json_encode` the form data headers. So my PHP code then ends up like so:

```
$user = array('id'=>5, 'first_name' => 'First', 'last_name' => 'Last');

$uch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:50115/Service1.svc/postUser");
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode("user=" . json_encode($user)));
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/json'
                                            ));
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($uch);
```

When I set the line:

```
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode("user=" . json_encode($user)));
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("user" => json_encode($user)));
--OR--
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                    http_build_query(array("user" => json_encode($user))));
--OR--
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($user));
```

there is no error in the PHP, the C# service does not return an error (I do have the setting to return exceptions set in the config), and the break-point on the function never gets hit.

On the C# side, I have my interface and service set up like so:

```
//Interface
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",
            BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, //Any other value, the break-point 
                                                //will not trigger
            RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "postUser")]
void PostUser(string user);

//Service
public void PostUser(string user)
{
    var request = user;
    int i = 5; //Debug set here
}
```

When the break-point hits, I am able to see that `user` has the value of:

```
user={"id":5,"first_name":"First","last_name":"Last"}
```

What I would like to have is for the value of `user` to simply be:

```
{"id":5,"first_name":"First","last_name":"Last"}
```

Is it possible to receive my response like this? If so, what do I need to change to accomplish it?

Comment: Is the value of `user` actually `user={"id":5,"first_name":"First","last_name":"Last"}`, or is that what appears in the debugger?  Wouldn't `json_encode($user)` do the trick?

Comment: @Tim That is the actual value of `user`. If I want just the json part, I have to use `var json = user.Split('=')[1];`

Comment: Caveat:  I don't know PHP, but looking at the documentation for `json_encode`, it appears (at a glance) that `json_encode($user)` would do the trick. So you would have `curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(json_encode($user));`.

Comment: When I use `json_encode($user)`, the break-point never gets hit and no errors are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple combinations in PHP and C#, I finally got it to work. In PHP, the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` needed to be set with:

```
curl_setopt($uch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array("user" => json_encode($user))));
```

Then, in C#, I needed to change `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` to `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`;